# Excluding an integer from an array to find the 2nd smallest

Tags: java, arrays, list, iteration

I have an assignment where my prof. will input an unspecified number of integers into my program, and my program will process the data accordingly **to assign a grade to each value and find the highest and lowest value**, however he always places a `-1` at the end of the data so that when `input<0` it will stop prompting for input.
The problem is my program isn't supposed to process the `-1`. It doesn't get added as a grade, but it is a part of the list of grades, so the lowest value is always `-1`.
I've tried writing code that would remove the `-1` from my array when detected as a part of the logic to evaluate a grade, but everything I've tried only returns errors.
How can I ignore the `-1` and find the next lowest value, or remove the `-1` from the list before evaluating?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hw5{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  int input = console.nextInt();
  ArrayList<Integer> GradeList = new ArrayList<>();

  while(input >= 0){
   input = console.nextInt();
   GradeList.add(input);
  }
  evaluateGrade(GradeList);
  System.out.print(GradeList);
}


 public static void evaluateGrade(List<Integer> Scores){ 
  int count = Scores.size();
  int high = Collections.max(Scores);
  int low = Collections.min(Scores);
  int Aplus = 0;
  int A = 0;
  int Amin = 0;
  int Bplus = 0;
  int B = 0;
  int Bmin = 0;
  int Cplus = 0;
  int C = 0;
  int Cmin = 0;
  int Dplus = 0;
  int D = 0;
  int Dmin = 0;
  int F = 0;

for(int i : Scores){
  if(i > 97){
    Aplus += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 93 && i <= 96){
    A += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 89 && i <= 92){
    Amin += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 85 && i <= 88){
    Bplus += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 81 && i <= 84){
    B += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 77 && i <= 80){
    Bmin += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 81 && i <= 84){
    B += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 77 && i <= 80){
     Bmin += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 76 && i <= 73){
    Cplus += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 69 && i <= 72){
    C += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 65 && i <= 68){
    Cmin += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 61 && i <= 64){
    Dplus += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 57 && i <= 60){
    D += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 53 && i <= 56){
    Dmin += 1;
  }
  else if(i >= 52 && i <= 0){
    F += 1;
  }
}

System.out.printf("Total number of grades = %d", count);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of A+'s = %d", Aplus);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of A's  = %d", A);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of A-'s = %d", Amin);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of B+'s = %d", Bplus);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of B's  = %d", B);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of B-'s = %d", Bmin);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of C+'s = %d", Cplus);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of C's  = %d", C);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of C-'s = %d", Cmin);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of D+'s = %d", Dplus);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of D's  = %d", D);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of D+'s = %d", Dmin);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("Number of F's  = %d", F);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("The highest grade = %d", high);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("The lowest grade = %d", low);
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
int input = console.nextInt();
ArrayList<Integer> GradeList = new ArrayList<>();

while(input >= 0){
   input = console.nextInt();
   GradeList.add(input);
}
```

To something like

```
List<Integer> gradeList = new ArrayList<>();
int input;

while ((input = console.nextInt()) >= 0) {
    gradeList.add(input);
}
```

Which programs to the `List` interface, follows the Java idiomatic convention of assignment and evaluation and observes standard variable naming conventions.